# How to click (or simulate a click) under a div in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have to create a `HighLighBox` that wraps certain number of elements without wrapping (in code) the elements that it should wrap.

I would like to click on the elements below the `div`, the radio input and the text input.

There is a snippet and codesandobx with the problem, just try clicking any input.

**Objetive:**

I have to keep the red line and be able to click the inputs.

```js
const HighLightBox = (props) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: 400,
          border: "1px solid red",
          ...props
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

 function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
}}>
      <HighLightBox width="12rem" height="5rem" top="-.3rem" left="35vw" />
      <div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Test" />
        </div>
        <hr />
        <label>
          {" "}
          One
          <input type="radio" name="test" value="one" />
        </label>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Two
          <input type="radio" name="test" value="two" />
        </label>
        <label>
          {" "}
          Three
          <input type="radio" name="test" value="Three" />
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

CodeSandox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-rgb-ocjjn?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If `HighLighBox` doesn't need any user interaction you can add `pointer-events: none;` to it and then your items behind should be clickable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the css `pointer-events: none;` to the red box, it prevents the browser from letting it be the focus of a click. So, the items underneath become the focus instead.

Note that if you use `pointer-events: none;` on something with child elements, the children ALSO become unclickable. You can enable the click on the children while disabling the parent by applying `pointer-events: all` on the children you want clickable. This doesn't look like it applies to this situation, but it is important to know :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Awesome explanation.

Answer (score 1):

add this to style of the red div:

```
 pointerEvents: "none",
```

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. Sorry! 